# Are curves just portions of connected circles of different radii?

Tags: circles, curves

I just had the question in my mind, can any curve be reduced to different portions of circumferences of circles with different radii, for example the curve of $\sin$ and $\cos$, and the curve of  $y = x^2$.

[for example , the curve in this picture is the green line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4nS3.png)

or do we just don't know the answer to that question ?

Comment: That question is a bit too vague I'd say. How would you reduce a straight line to different portions of circles?

Comment: @MisterRiemann where have I mentioned a straight line, I'm talking about curves

Comment: A straight line is a curve according to the definitions that I am familiar with (see [Wikipedia - Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve)). In that case, what definition of a curve are you using?

Comment: @MisterRiemann sorry I am not a math major so I don't know the definitions, but what I meant by a curve is something like the curve of sine and cosine and the curve of y = x^2

Comment: Well, to get an answer to questions such as yours, one needs to set up the definitions properly first to be able to get a satisfactory answer. I don't want to discourage you, but "[...] something like the curve of sine [...]" is too vague to work with, and I don't really think that there is a good answer your question.

Comment: @MisterRiemann let's just say by a curve I mean something that is not a straight line, do you think that this is a proper definition ?

Comment: I think you will find the concept of an "osculating circle" interesting - it is the collection of circles that "best approximates" a (sufficiently smooth) curve at any point. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OsculatingCircle.html

Comment: @CalvinKhor thank you, that's very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A circle has a constant curvature. In general, curves do not, their curvature varies continuously. So the answer is negative.

You can approximate a curve with well-chosen circular arcs, but this remains an approximation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have made [an interactive Desmos plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/i0sadl2z6s) that graphs any function $f$ you choose, and its osculating circles. Here is $\frac{x^2}{10} + \sin x$ and its osculating circle at $x\approx 1$,
[image]
The circle and the graph agree "to second order" but not necessarily any better(to answer your question). They give a better indication of the local behavior than just the tangent lines; for instance, the graph curves in the same direction as its osculating circle.

To create the Desmos plot, I just used the formulae readily available on Wikipedia on [osculating circles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osculating_circle) and [curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature). I was pleased to see the smoothly varying osculating circles after so little effort. Hopefully someone else enjoys this as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot , that helps